# Find Dominant color of an Image in C

Tags: c, colors, gdkpixbuf

I have an image in GdkPixbuf format which is to be drawn on a cairo surface. How to get the most dominant color in the image which could be in svg or png format ?

Comment: How is “dominant color” defined?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen most common pixel of the Image rgb.